# Apache Camel: Response is get lost when reached explicitly on route

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting a strange situation at the code below which simply routes request to Google and returns response.

It works well but when I activate the line commented out as *"//Activating this line causes empty response on browser"*   to print out returned response from http endpoint (Google), response is disappear, nothing is displayed on browser. I thought it might be related with input stream of http response which can be consumed only once and I activated [Stream Caching](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html) on context but nothing changed.

Apache Camel version is 2.11.0

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    public class GoogleCaller {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8081/myapp/")
                .to("jetty://http://www.google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
                .process(new Processor() {

                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Response received from Google, is streamCaching = " + exchange.getContext().isStreamCaching());
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------IN MESSAGE--------------------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------OUT MESSAGE--------------------------------------------------------------");
                        //System.out.println(exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class)); //Activating this line causes empty response on browser
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        context.setTracing(true);
        context.setStreamCaching(true);
        context.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use a custom processor to process the message, you should keep it in mind the in message of the exchange has response message from the google, if you are using exchange.getOut(), camel will create a new empty out message for you and treat it as response message.

Because you don't set the out message body in the processor, it makes sense that you get the empty response in the browser.

Comment: AS Willem rightly pointed out, when you use exchange.getOut(), it creates a new message and that is why you're losing out on the message down the route. You can explicitly set Out message by using - exchange.getOut.setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)) but it is always better to change the In message itself..Read more - http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: @ferhatkul Don't use .getOut() for retreiving stuff - just for setting a new message. In your case - don't use it.

The "out" message from one processor (jetty or what not) will be the "in" message to the next. The behaviour of the custom processor is to copy the "in" message to the "out" message once the `process` method is done executing.

Comment: @U2one, the link http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html  you provided is the where clarifies everything, Thank you

Comment: @Petter, <the "out" message from one processor (jetty or what not) will be the "in" message to the next.> is key sentence of the issue, Thank you, i got what i missed

Comment: @Willem, I supposed that IN message holds request and OUT message holds response from Google that is why I tried to print response in next processor by getting from OUT, but now it is clear with "OUT will be IN of next" which is more reasonable in terms of processing during a route. Thanks for your answer